# Objective-C protocol not being recognized in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

We are in the process of migrating existing classes from Objective-C to Swift. In a view controller class I am implementing a protocol and attempting to add the view controller as a delegate of an object contained within it. When I try to add 'self' as the object's delegate in Swift I get the following compile error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type '((ListenerProtocol) -> Void)?
```

Here is the existing implementation in Obj-C

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <ListenerProtocol> ...
```

And adding the class as the listener (delegate)

```
[manager addListener:self];
```

This works without any problems. But the Swift version fails in what seems like the same code. Here is the Swift version of the same call:

```
@objc class SomeSwiftViewController: UIViewController, ListenerProtocol ...
```

And the call to 'addListener'

```
manager?.addListener(self)
```

I have verified successfully that 'self' is a ListenerProtocol object at runtime by checking:

```
if self.conformsToProtocol(ListenerProtocol){
    // ...
}
```

In the object containing the delegate property the addListener method is defined in Objective-C as follows:

```
- (void)addListener:(id<ListenerProtocol>)listener {
    // ...
}
```

The Swift class completely implements all of the methods defined in ListenerProtocol. I can't understand why this doesn't work in Swift. Can anyone make a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show where `manager.addListener` is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `ListenerProtocol`, it's with the protocol that `manager` implements. Judging by the type, `addListener` appears to be provided as an optional method. Notice the question mark at the end of the function type:

```
((ListenerProtocol) -> Void)?
```

This usually happens with (actually, I think that it *only* happens with) Objective-C optional protocol methods.

You should be able to write `manager?.addListener?(self)` or `manager?.addListener!(self)`.

Comment: I think you meant "`addListener` appears to be provided as an optional method" (not addManager). Another possibility is that `addListener` is a optional property on manager.